# How to get term name using PHP code in views? Drupal 6!

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

how can i get term name of current term using PHP code? I am using it in views. Thank you.

I dont know why, but the below code doesant work:

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
$name = $term->name;
```

Comment: are you using global php field for this purpose?

Comment: yes, i am using global php field. Do i need to have this "function" in template.php?

Comment: From where did you get $tid variable?

Comment: I just found this piece of code and i put it in php field in views. What more i must to do?

Comment: This is undoubtedly the wrong way to go https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2013/12/26/44497-people-are-wrong-how-to-never-use-views-php/ perhaps you could let us know what you're trying to achieve and we can suggest a better option?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the term name of current node in views you can make use of `Content: All taxonomy terms field`. There is no need for diving into PHP code.

Comment: As i wrote, i need term name of current term, not node! Lets say i am on term page and need to get term name of current term using PHP code.

Comment: Will you update the question with fields and filters you used in your views?

Comment: I am not sure, i understand you well.

Comment: Let me know if you use views UI or what?

Comment: yes, if you mean views UI module.

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of your views in your question?